# Python how to see the data in the column/row format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do is how to see the data in the column/rows format. I have imported the data, then modified the data and then added train and test data. I want to see the modified data in the column/rows format and I am not sure how to do, here is the code I am running.
Error is name 'read_modify' is not defined

```
dataset = pd.read_excel("Q4FY19Dataset.xlsx")
dataset = dataset.fillna(value=0)
dataset["STATUS_HEALTH_CODE"][dataset["STATUS_HEALTH_CODE"]==0]='000'
dataset["PHASE"][dataset["PHASE"]==0]='000'
dataset["OPP_STATUS_DERIVED"][dataset["OPP_STATUS_DERIVED"]==0]='000'
dataset["OPPORTUNITY_STATUS"][dataset["OPPORTUNITY_STATUS"]==0]='000'
dataset["EVP4"][dataset["PHASE"]==0]='000'
dataset["EVP3"][dataset["EVP3"]==0]='000'
dataset["EVP2"][dataset["EVP2"]==0]='000'
#create_evp_win_rate_lookup()
dataset=modify_dataset(dataset)
X_train=dataset
X_train ["TE_OR_TR"]=0
y_train =dataset[required_y_column]
y_train["TE_OR_TR"]=0 # 0 means train # till here no error
read_modify = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset) # code to see the data in row/column format
read_modify.head() # if I run this code, it give me error
```

Comment: a = pd.DataFrame(), followed by a.head() works for me. I don't see how you can have an undefined error unless the read_modify = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset) is giving you an error?

Comment: ```read_modify.pipe(print)```

Comment: Got, it worked, I forgot to use this command a = pd.DataFrame(),